# connection problem mongoDB with MongoClient

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have some problem about connection to my mongoDB with MongoClient.

```
const { MnogoClient , ObjectID} = require('mongodb')
const id = new ObjectID()
console.log(id)

const connectionURL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'
const databaseName = 'task-manager'
MnogoClient.connect(connectionURL , {useNewUrlParser: true}, (error, client)=>{
if(error){
    return console.log(error)
}

const db = client.db(databaseName)
//insertOne is asyncronuse opration and beacuse we use callback function 

//for the collection we can assign my own property object id
db.collection('users').insertOne({
    _id: id,
    name: 'Mahdi',
    age: 24
} , (error , result)=>{
    if(error){
        return console.log('Unable to insert the document')
    }
    console.log(result.ops)
    
})})
```

i get TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'connect').

Comment: 1. You cannot use `useNewUrlParser` in the client options
2. `ObjectID` should be changed to `ObjectId`. The original has been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

i think you have a typos error I can see there **MnogoClient.connect**

```
MongoClient.connect(connectionURL , {useNewUrlParser: true}, (error, client)=>{
if(error){
    return console.log(error)
}
....
....
})
```

Comment: The code has several typos.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { MongoClient, ObjectID } = require('mongodb') // It's Mongo not mnogo

MongoClient
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mongodb version to "mongodb": "3.1.10", It will work for sure.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).